# HTTP ERROR 505. Установил Symfony после чего стал получать такую ошибку

Tags: php, apache, symfony

```
<VirtualHost 81.177.140.127>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/tracex/public"

    ServerName 81.177.140.127

   <Directory "/var/www/tracex/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Все вроде правильно. Хз что не так

Выводит это вместо страницы приветствия 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в index.php 
код вообще не менял

```
> <?php
> 
> use App\Kernel; use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug; use
> Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv; use
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
> 
> require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
> 
> // The check is to ensure we don't use .env in production if
> (!isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV'])) {
>     if (!class_exists(Dotenv::class)) {
>         throw new \RuntimeException('APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for
> configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load
> variables from a .env file.');
>     }
>     (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env'); }
> 
> $env = $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] ?? 'dev'; $debug = (bool)
> ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG'] ?? ('prod' !== $env));
> 
> if ($debug) {
>     umask(0000);
> 
>     Debug::enable(); }
> 
> if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
>     Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST); }
> 
> if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
>     Request::setTrustedHosts(explode(',', $trustedHosts)); }
> 
> $kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug); $request =
> Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request);
> $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Вот логи

```
[Tue Jun 12 17:26:09.425083 2018] [:error] [pid 12419] [client 171.33.255.2:54430] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /var/www/tracex/public/index.php o$
[Tue Jun 12 17:29:04.305256 2018] [:error] [pid 12420] [client 171.33.255.2:54420] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /var/www/tracex/public/index.php o$
[Tue Jun 12 17:29:05.478780 2018] [:error] [pid 12418] [client 171.33.255.2:54421] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in /var/www/tracex/public/index.php o$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619312/switch-php-versions-on-commandline-ubuntu-16-04 Вот там расписано как установить несколько версий PHP и переключаться между ними

Answer (score 0):

Логи не показывают строку, но мне кажется проблема в версии PHP, у вас используется оператор `??` который появился в версии 7.0

Comment: Я сейчас посмотрел и увидел   что когда я запускаю команду php -v  он мне возвращает php 7.2 но в браузере команда phpinfo(); возвращает  Php 5.6

Comment: Как думаете из за чего это ?

Comment: @EMOMALIEV apache значит php 5.6 использует

Comment: Как можно это исправить ? Очень много времени потратил :(

Comment: Просто подключаете модуль php7 к апачу, это легко гуглится

Comment: Странно везде говориться про установку php 7, но у меня то она установлена.